# myOpenID Delegation for StackOverflow.com, what did I do wrong?

Tags: support, openid

I am in the process of building a whole new website on my domain, and to begin with, I'd like to add OpenID delegation to it, so that I can use its domain URL to sign into OpenID authenticated websites, like StackOverflow.com.

I'm using [myOpenID](http://www.myopenid.com/) as my OpenID provider.

So I added this to my website `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://lassevk.myopenid.com/" />
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://lassevk.myopenid.com" />
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://www.myopenid.com/xrds?username=lassevk.myopenid.com" />
```

This is taken from the [myOpenID website on delegation](https://www.myopenid.com/help#own_domain).

However, when I try to log into StackOverflow.com using the OpenID name `www.vkarlsen.no`, I get this StackOverflow.com error:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>   No OpenID endpoint found.

---

**Edit**: This works on SuperUser.com, can StackOverflow have a cache of my old, incorrect, website content?

---

If I try `www.vkarlsen.no/default.aspx` I'm redirected to a myOpenID.com page that says:

> myOpenID is not authorized to verify that http://www.vkarlsen.no/default.aspx is your identifier. If it is your identifier, you can set up myOpenID to verify it. See [the help page](https://www.myopenid.com/help#own_domain) for more information.

That link goes to the same page, clearly I did something wrong.

However, and here's the fun part. If I try to log into StackOverflow.com, using the OpenID name `trunk.vkarlsen.no`, it then asks me if I want to associate the name with my account.

However, the files on that site is 100% exactly the same as on the main site.

```
C:\inetpub>fc /B wwwroot\default.aspx wwwroot_trunk\default.aspx
Comparing files WWWROOT\default.aspx and WWWROOT_TRUNK\DEFAULT.ASPX
FC: no differences encountered
```

The site URLs are:

1. http://www.vkarlsen.no (production)
2. http://trunk.vkarlsen.no (source control trunk, for testing purposes)

So, can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Currently, the following two OpenID names are associated with my StackOverflow.com account:

1. lassevk.myopenid.com
2. www.vkarlsen.no/index.php?title=main_page

That second name there is from my old site, which I'm hoping I can get rid of it I can just get my new site content working.

Notes:

1. I found this meta-question: [Failure to log in with delegated OpenId](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42152/failure-to-log-in-with-delegated-openid), says something related to delegation was solved march 16th, however I'm having these problems today, march 21st, so I'm guessing I have a different problem.

Comment: This sounds like a programming question, not really a Stack Overflow problem.

Comment: I'd be happy to move it, but since SO is the site I'm having problems with logging into, I'm betting on it being moved to superuser or closed fairly quick.

Comment: I've now successfully associated `www.vkarlsen.no` with my account on superuser.com, yet stackoverflow.com maintains that there is no openid provider on my site. Can their web-retrieval software have a cache? I had some errors in my code earlier today when I first tried, so perhaps it has old content?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, StackOverflow currently caches OpenID discovery results.  Waiting a day or so may get it to recognize the change.

Comment: Ok, good to know. I'll accept your answer when I've verified that it works (not that I don't trust you ;))

Comment: Did it work, Lasse?